# Android include "?" in Linkify text

Tags: android, linkify

I used the method found in this link [Android: Linkify TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview)

```
public static void addLink(TextView textView, String patternToMatch,
        final String link) {
    Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
        @Override public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
            return link;
        }
    };
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Pattern.compile(patternToMatch), null, null,
            filter);
}
```

My function call

```
addLink(text, "Forgot password?", "http://www.abc.com");
```

But the result ends up with "**Forgot password**?" The bold portion is blue and underlined. How do I include the "?" to become blue and underlined as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument is *pattern*  and you are adding `?` (Regular expression character class char).

try this,

```
addLink(text, "Forgot password[?]", "http://www.abc.com");
```