# Href with different link shown to user than actual link Android

Tags: android, anchor

I append extra info to a url that I do not want to show to the user in the textView.  Here is what I am doing, but the href link is not the one getting used. This code goes to www.google.com, not the link I put in the href tag. My link is not to Google, just showing this as example of functionality. Any ideas?

```
String agreementText = context.getString(R.string.PhraseAgreement_Part1);
Spanned fullEulaText = Html.fromHtml(agreementText + "\n <a href=‘http://www.google.com?pcode=somePartner’>www.google.com</a>");
Linkify.addLinks((Spannable) fullEulaText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

My textView has the tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

And my xml has the  android:autoLink="web"

UPDATE SOLVED:
It turns out it was a combination of items.  First, in my xml, I needed to remove:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Then, I also needed to remove:

```
Linkify.addLinks((Spannable) fullEulaText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

And for the textView that I am setting the text (Spannable) to:

```
tv.setText(TermsAndConditionsUtilities.buildAgreementText(this));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Now I get a url displayed to the user that has an anchor tag url that appends extra info onto to send to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Linkify TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview)

Comment: @PankajKumar  I have searched other answers and I am doing all the required coding.  The difference with mine is that I am showing an actual link, but wanting to direct to that link with info appended to the end of it.  I don't see this example anywhere else, and no matter what I have tried...nothing has directed to the link with the append.