# Linkify is adding %20 in my url and is not opening exact url

Tags: android, linkify

i am opening a website using linkify feature of android and getting %20 in my url when opening from my device so what should i do?

here is what i am doing

```
license=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.find_us_tv3);

    license.setTextSize(18);
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("p"+"[page stackoverflow]+stackoverflow");

    license.setText(" Open the demo page stackoverflow.");
    license.setLinksClickable(true);
    Linkify.addLinks(license, pattern, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "http:/" in your code of
"*Linkify.addLinks(license, pattern, "http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")*"
 twice doesn't help.

Just use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
Linkify.addLinks(license, pattern, "http://");
```

Where the text that you mention in `pattern` should be a part of the text you set in your `TextView`

Refer: [linkify blog link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)

Comment: actually i have text about 5 lines and i am adding pattern for that given word like license. and want to open a specific web page onclick.

Comment: you can just specify the word in pattern, that should work...for your textview

Comment: is it opening the page or not?

Comment: no my link is same as
Linkify.addLinks(license, pattern, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
and adding %20 from device.(http hidden in comment)

Comment: pls change your pattern.compile and evaluate the string value. Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview), where is it adding the %20 ?

Comment: no its not working @user2450263...
and please why everybody is voting down :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView tvWeblink = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
        tvWeblink.setTypeface(LandingScreen.font);

        tvWeblink.setClickable(true);
        tvWeblink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "By pressing this It will open stack overflow page <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/\"> ask a question. </a>.";
        tvWeblink.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```