# Textview multiple underline text getting onClick dynamically in android

Tags: android, html, textview

I should html content load on textview its ok and display well but how to handle multiple underline word getting onclick dynamically.

How can i getting click like as Phnom Penh, Siem Reap & so on etc..????

Thanks in advance

**See snapshot**

[image]

Comment: try linkify api for textview

Comment: `android:linksClickable="true"`

Comment: Not getting for your answer if you have link then send me plz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview

Comment: Thanks for giving link, i will try

Comment: @diva: Yes got the clickable area on underline text but how to perform this action ????

Comment: few of example there specifies the same

Comment: @diva: not handle on click on that underline text plz tell me

Comment: so the answer accepted below didnt solved the issue?

Comment: Yes not getting solution as well. what i need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so happy bcos I should find out answer for this quesiton, which i need to it dynamically solutions.

Just, go on this link for blog and step by step which is our need to dynamically solution there.

**SuN Blog**

http://suniljp.blogspot.in/search/label/TextView_%20%20underline%20text%20click

:)

Answer (score 2):

Just put below line in your code:

```
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It will open link which is attached to that word in html.