# Clickable telephone numbers in TextView text

Tags: android

I have a text view that has telephone numbers as its text, I want when the user clicks on the telephone number the application calls the number, I was able to do that using android's `Linkify.addLinks` method, but this only works when there is only one telephone number in the text view, but when there is two numbers it is not working, the two numbers come in the following format:

"94225445454 / 621189452"

The `Linkify.addLinks` only makes one number clickable and the other is not, anybody knows how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Linkify.addLinks` also take pattern to match. see following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697453/3871491 check this

Comment: try to separate the numbers first using some delimeter like `,` then try. Also try to first format the number using `PhoneNumberUtils.format()`

Comment: but the telephone may be in different formats, how can i process that?