# Android- getSpans() always returns an array of length 0

Tags: android, spannablestring

This has been driving me crazy:

```
String message = "Here is some example test with URLs from mattheworiordan.com.
    Any of the URLs which are prefixed with www. should become URLs such as www.mattheworiordan.com/path_name.html
    And an explicit URL such as http://www.mattheworiordan.com/ should become a URL.
    Emails such as matt@google.com should become links to.
    Or email mailto links such as mailto:matt@google.com should become links to.
    And of course lets not forget querstryings such as http://mattheworiordan.com/?test-param=true_or_false" 

SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(message);
URLSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.ALL);
Log.v("data_", "length:" + Integer.toString(spans.length));
```

The length of the `URLSpan[]` array is always 0. What am I doing wrong here and how can I parse all urls in the `String`?

Edit: `Html.fromHtml(message)` in place of the message parameter returns the same result.

Comment: it is just text, you don't have any span in the text

Answer (score 2):

It is because you don't have any spans. In  the case of `Html.fromHtml` to get a `URLSpan`, you have to use the tag `<a href`. E.g.

```
String message = "Here is some example test with URLs from mattheworiordan.com.
      Any of the URLs which are prefixed with www. should become URLs such as www.mattheworiordan.com/path_name.html
      And an explicit URL such as <a href='http://www.mattheworiordan.com/'>http://www.mattheworiordan.com/</a> should become a URL.
      Emails such as matt@google.com should become links to.
      Or email mailto links such as mailto:matt@google.com should become links to.
      And of course lets not forget querstryings such as http://mattheworiordan.com/?test-param=true_or_false"
```

will yield `1`. If you don't want to use `Html`, then you will have to set the `URLSpan`s programatically

Answer (score 2):

Simple error. Try calling Linkify.addLinks *before* calling getSpans.

Comment: Thanks! See example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview.