# Setting minimum length for auto link

Tags: android, linkify, autolink

I have a big paragraph which may have numbers, email addresses and links. So I have to set  `setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.WEB_URLS)` for my textview.

The content may contain digits of varying numbers. I want to set numbers having atleast 8 digits as phone number links.(For Eg : 12345678)

Is it possible to set minimum length for Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS ? 
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use [Linkify.MatchFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.MatchFilter.html) to specify minimum length or your some other requirements. There is not any direct way provided by Android.

Also somewhere in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview) found some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

use below pattern :

```
    SpannableString buffer = new SpannableString(text);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]\d{7,9}$");
    Linkify.addLinks(buffer , pattern,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. I researched this phenomenon :-)

To set the minimum length for a phone number, use this code:

```
private final Linkify.MatchFilter matchFilterForPhone = new Linkify.MatchFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
        int digitCount = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                digitCount++;
                if (digitCount >= 6) { // HERE: number 6 is minimum
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

To properly format and link phone numbers, use:

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(myTekst);
Linkify.addLinks(s, android.util.Patterns.PHONE, "tel:", matchFilterForPhone, Linkify.sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
```

Now place the formatted `s` in your TextView, and call:

```
findViewById(R.id.message).setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);
findViewById(R.id.message).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

That's all. Thanks for vote.